# chrome.downloads.download ignoring parameters after 'url'

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a simple extension that will automatically download an image from our company website to a directory.  The problem is that `chrome.downloads.download` seems to ignore every parameter after 'url'.
It downloads the file.  But keeps the original name, and ignores sub-directories.  It will append a (#) if the file already exits instead of overwriting as specified in the code.

I have tried various ways of implementing the object passed to chrome.downloads.download, including creating a object with all the parameters and passing that object.  I've tried using quotes even where it didn't make sense.
I have tried reformatting the filename parameter, even giving it a fixed value of "foo.jpg".  I have tried doing this in both the content.js and bs.js.
I have confirmed that the filename is passed to the background script and the value is accessible by displaying it with an `alert()` in the background script

```
//Manifest.js (important parts)
"permissions": ["downloads","webNavigation"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["bs.js"],
    "Persistent": false
    },
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js"]
    },
    {
        "matches": ["https://mycompany.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }

    ]

//Content.js (important parts)
var $imgs = $('#spec_jpg img');
var url = "https:" + $imgs.attr('src');
var filename ="specificationArchive/" +  url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); //edited
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({url: url, filename: filename});

//bs.js (whole thing)
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender){
      chrome.downloads.download ( { url: request.url,
      filename: request.filename,
      conflictAction: "overwrite",
      saveAs: false }
      )
    }
);
```

The extension does download the file, but I expected it to save it into a sub-directorycalled specificationArchive.  I also expected it to overwrite an existing file instead of appending a (#) to the end of the name.  Even when passing an absolute string for the filename, I get the file's original name

Comment: See the documentation for `filename` parameter: "Absolute paths, empty paths, and paths containing back-references ".." will cause an error".

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I did read that during my initial troubleshooting, but it did not apply.  The code throws no errors and the file does download, just not with the name specified.  I tried using various values for `filename ` to ensure I was referencing a relative path from the Downloads folder.  I have even tried `var filename = "foo.jpg" ` in content.cs but it insists on using the original filename.  I also tried using `filename: "foo.jpg" ` in bs.js in case something wasn't being passed correctly.  The original filename is still preserved.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me.  I noticed the error using absolute paths and corrected it during my initial troubleshoot.  It got copied over to the post when I was testing.  The leading slash was not ignored as it throws an error and the file does not download.  Without it, or even with the line changed to `var filename = "foo.jpg"` the file does download and throws no error, but the path is not used.  Even changing the line bs.js to `filename: 'foo.jpg' ` does not change the behavior and file is saved with the original name.

Comment: Try providing the file name in chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename listener.

Comment: That one did it!  Thanks a lot.  Now I just have to figure out how to list this post as solved. :-)  I'm new to StackOverlfow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided by wOxxOm is to add an additional listener.  Here's the code that was added to bs.js

```
//bs.js
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
suggest({filename: "specificationArchive/" + item.filename, conflictAction: 'overwrite'});
});
```

Once this was included it saved to the directory listed.
Thanks again.